# Is it possible to set 2FA so that it cannot be undone in any way - password for /etc/pam.d/common-auth or total deactivation rescue mode?

Tags: ubuntu, security, password, rescue, 2-factor-authentication

I would like to be sure that without knowing the password no one can delete / edit the 2FA credentials  etc

can I securely password protect them or are there other ways to achieve such a result?

I explain exactly how I see it . Folder with file /etc/pam.d/common-auth - gives information that linux is supposed to require 2FA code. On the system every operation requires me to code - root login or sudo command.

The problem is - that in rescue mode this entry without a problem can be deleted and thus disable 2FA - that is 2FA in principle has no meaning if I can disable it without having the 2FA code.

There is a topic similar to mine (but with U2F). But there the author has concerns that if he loses the U2F conflict he will lose access to the system. Why no answer wrote such a simple workaround as rescue mode ? It is a little strange https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167691/passwordless-login-with-yubikey-5-nfc/But

There were really a lot of answers there, and everyone warns that he may lose access to the system. So I'll ask again. Is it possible to set 2FA so that it cannot be undone in any way (like editing a common-auth file in rescue mode?

Comment: Run `ls -l /etc`. You'll see that everything there and its subdirectories is owned by the root, and root is the only one with write access. So only root or users with `sudo` privileges can do anything but view files therein.

Comment: yes but I want to set an extra password on this file in case someone knows the admin password (for example some backdoor detects it)

Comment: @Jeahos that's not how file systems on Unix-alike systems work, sorry! Either a user has privileges to do something to a file, or they don't. Also, if someone knows the superuser credential, nothing that your system in any form can read is safe anymore: the superuser (what you call "admin") is able to just do *anything*. Including, for example, accessing the raw hard drive, circumventing the file system, and just looking for the contents of said file there. Or they could just monitor all key presses, including that of entering a password, which would immediately render that password useless.

Comment: Essentially, once something untrustworthy runs as super user, it's game over: anything on your machine that's not encrypted and only gets decrypted **on a different machine or within special security enclaves that your computer otherwise has no access to** (that might for example be stuff that gets decrypted *inside the chip of a smart card that you put into a smart card reader, and never leaves the smart card*, but not a file that your CPU decrypts into your RAM after you entering a passphrase) is compromised. Game over.

Comment: I think you might be doing something very interesting – securing a system against malicious use – but your current approach is sadly not possible on the Linux. So, for your last question "ways to achieve such a result": it's not quite clear what you mean with "such results". It seems like you're trying to protect from some sort of attack, but we don't know against what specifically, and what you actually need to protect! The "password on /etc/pam.d/common-auth" neither works nor seems to be what you *actually* need to protect. Can you be more explicit with your *threat modeling*?

Comment: Come to think of it, I think we've got an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks for the comprehensive explanation of the topic. Hence my concern as well as my question. My question is as follows. Why then can't I log in and perform all operations as SUDO using both the password to the system and the 2FA code? why this solution is not possible - isn't this the right question in the context of security???

The PAM application allows you to set every sudo operation to require the 2FA code. Why, then, give any door to disable this security in RESCUE mode? After all, a conscious user who knows what he is doing may want to have much more control, right?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I explain exactly how I see it .

Folder with file /etc/pam.d/common-auth - gives information that linux is supposed to require 2FA code. 

On the system every operation requires me to code - root login or sudo command. The problem is - that in rescue mode this entry without a problem can be deleted and thus disable 2FA - that is 2FA in principle has no meaning if I can disable it without having the 2FA code - do you get it?

Comment: That solution is not possible because, as described above, once you're superuser, there's *nothing* in your system that can *stop* you. All password prompts are pure decorational.

Comment: The "data" has no way to protect itself. It's just bits on some storage device or in RAM. So, if you are the user who can read RAM and any storage device without anything in your system able to stop you, why would you kindly enter your password? In other words, if you're the owner of a very massive battering ram, why wou you kindly knock on the door of the castle and ask for permission to tear down the gate?

Comment: @Jeahos Please don't answer in comments, instead [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/738635/edit) your question. Everything relevant should be added there, including the "why", so it's readily available for the members of the community.

Comment: @MarcusMüller So please see the topic similar to mine. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167691/passwordless-login-with-yubikey-5-nfc/But there the author has concerns that if he loses the U2F conflict he will lose access to the system. Why no answer wrote such a simple workaround as rescue mode ? It is a little strange

Comment: I think people assumed that he had no way to boot into a different os/rescue os, for example through SecureBoot. I'm not them! Also note that he might be authenticating against active directory/kerberos or similar, so being able to access good own computer to the fullest extent doesn't mean he can access data residing on a different computer.

Comment: Note that the accepted answer also shows the trick here: the full machine is encrypted. So, modification of any authentication mechanisms requires the ability to decrypt the whole storage device (and not some files on it).

Comment: @MarcusMüller But I don't understand. How could they assume that there is no possibility to run rescue? And here it is not necessary to have another disk, iso on pednrive or something. After all, rescue mode is started from within grub by selecting the appropriate option, so anyone installing ubuntu and other popular linux has rescue mode at their fingertips and thus can disable 2FA very easily. So I still do not understand...

Comment: They can boot a rescue system, and overwrite whatever part of the authentication mechanism they want to. No problem. What they cannot do is decrypt the user data. Encrypted means encrypted – if you don't know the key, you can't know the content.  And because they're not an attacker, who might, for example, install a daemon to wait until the right user decrypts their home directory to then steal all the data, but the actual user, nobody knows the key, and the data is lost forever, like tears in the rain…

Answer (score 2):

Any file or directory in Linux can be password protected<sup>*</sup>. However processes need access to files, and basic processes like the ones an authentication service uses have no means for providing passphrases.

In any modern system passwords are encrypted. Any encryption can be cracked, but it's a very long process, and the success depends largely on the complexity of the password itself. In the case of cracking for example Linux root password, one must commonly first gain access to files and directories that require providing at minimum a sudoer password.

Rootkits in Linux are few and far between. The weakest link in any security chain is always the human element; thus root password should be sufficiently complex and kept well protected. Physical access to the system must be restricted to prevent bypassing security measures by booting into Rescue mode.

Security is always a cat and mouse -game, and security is always lagging step behind. A new threat must emerge before a system can be hardened against it. In the end there is no absolutely unbreakable security, only the level where the gains of breaking it are sufficiently substantial to warrant the effort. This means generally governmental, military or major global corporations or institutions.

<sup>*</sup>Sources:

- [How to Password Protect a Folder in Linux](https://itsfoss.com/password-protect-folder-linux/) (IT'S FOSS, 10 Jan 2023)
- [Protecting your files and folders](https://linuxhint.com/protect-files-folders/) (LinuxHint 2022)
- [How to password protect a file in Linux](https://www.garron.me/en/linux/password-protect-file.html) (Guillermo Garron, 05 Sep 2020)
- [How To Password Protect Files In Linux with GnuPG?](https://www.linuxfordevices.com/tutorials/linux/password-protect-files-in-linux) (Linux for Devices, 25 Apr 2021)
- and others

Comment: yeah, on Unixoids like Linux, files are *never* password-protected. *Logging in as a user with a set of privileges that include working on some files* is password-protected, if anything. And even that is a stretch – actually, it's a bit of a lie: if your process has the privilege to change the user it runs as, then it can do that without ever needing any password. The kernel doesn't care about passwords. It's just that the programs we usually use to let users log in canonically agreed to all use the same "dance" to verify a user is the user they claim to be, which often involves a password.

Comment: @MarcusMüller "unixoids" :-D

Comment: Thank you for the references. EncFS (and Veracrypt) are interesting options in that they layer the encryption

Comment: @roaima Thank _you_ for reminding me (again...) how it's supposed to be done :-)

Comment: So please see the topic similar to mine. But there the author has concerns that if he loses the U2F conflict he will lose access to the system. Why no answer wrote such a simple workaround as rescue mode ? It is a little strange

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167691/passwordless-login-with-yubikey-5-nfc/

Comment: There were really a lot of answers there, and everyone warns that he may lose access to the system. So I'll ask again. Is it possible to set 2FA so that it cannot be undone in any way (like editing a common-auth file in rescue mode?

Comment: @Jeahos, again, please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/738635/edit) your question and put new info there. Please. Try to formulate it so that you have there one single clear question. As we're now getting to the _actual_ issue, you should also edit the title appropriately.

Comment: I changed the topic and added new content, Is that what you meant ?

Comment: Yes. The original was a classic X/Y problem, but now there's a clear question with enough background that people can actually concentrate on how to help you resolve our actual problem :-) However I'm leaving my answer up, as the changes don't invalidate it.